# Creating publishing page on SP2010 with CSOM (15) Cannot find proxy for type with id

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, csom

While trying to create a publishing page in the pages library, I get unexplained error.Additional information: Cannot find proxy for type with id "{55927360-235b-4ace-9dcf-c574d6e517ea}".

Could it be CSOM is only safe for SP2013 and up?

```
private static void BuildPage(ClientContext clientContext, PublishingWeb pWeb, ListItem pageLayout, List pages, string aiName)
{
    // Create a publishing page
    PublishingPageInformation publishingPageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
    publishingPageInfo.Name = aiName;
    publishingPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = pageLayout;
    PublishingPage publishingPage = pWeb.AddPublishingPage(publishingPageInfo);
    if (pages.ForceCheckout || pages.EnableVersioning)
    {
        publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
        publishingPage.ListItem.File.Publish(string.Empty);
        if (pages.EnableModeration)
        {
             publishingPage.ListItem.File.Approve(string.Empty);
        }
    }
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
    //Here the error is Additional information: Cannot find proxy for type with id "{55927360-235b-4ace-9dcf-c574d6e517ea}".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For targeting different versions of SharePoint the separate versions of CSOM SDK are intended, in case of SharePoint 2010  it is [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786)).

You are getting this error since [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.aspx) is not exposed via CSOM API in SharePoint 2010.

---

**How to create a publishing page via SharePoint 2010 CSOM API**

The example shows how to create a *publishing page*  (it mimics to some extent [`PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.addpublishingpage.aspx)):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SharePoint2010.CSOM.Extensions
{
    public static class PublishingPage
    {
        public static void Create(List pagesList,ListItem pageLayout, string pageName, string pageContent)
        {
            var ctx = (ClientContext) pagesList.Context;
            const string publishingPageTemplate =
                "<%@ Page Inherits=\"Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c\" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=\"~TemplatePageUrl\" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=\"~masterurl/custom.master\" %>";
            var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                Url = pageName,
                Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publishingPageTemplate),
                Overwrite = true
            };
            var pageFile = pagesList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
            var pageItem = pageFile.ListItemAllFields;

            if (!ctx.Site.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Site);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            pageItem["PublishingPageLayout"] = string.Format("{0}, {1}", pageLayout["FileRef"], pageLayout["Title"]);
            pageItem["PublishingPageContent"] = pageContent;
            pageItem.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }


        public static ListItem GetPageLayout(ClientContext ctx, string name)
        {
            var masterPagesList = ctx.Site.GetCatalog((int) ListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
            var items = masterPagesList.GetItems(CreatePageLayoutByNameQuery(name));
            ctx.Load(items);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return items.Count == 1 ? items[0] : null;
        }

        private static CamlQuery CreatePageLayoutByNameQuery(string name)
        {
            var qry = new CamlQuery();
            qry.ViewXml = "<View>" +
                              "<Query>" +
                                   "<Where>" +
                                      "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>{0}</Value></Eq>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                              "</Query>" +
                          "</View>";
            qry.ViewXml = String.Format(qry.ViewXml,name);
            return qry;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri.ToString(), userName, password))
{
    var pagesList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
    var pageLayout = PublishingPage.GetPageLayout(ctx, "ArticleLeft.aspx");
    PublishingPage.Create(pagesList, pageLayout,"Welcome.aspx","<h1>Welcome</h1>");
}
```